# Responsive email template works in browser, but fails in all email clients

Tags: responsive-design, html-email

I created a responsive email template. I used tables and tried to keep it simple for email. I did use CSS in the head instead of inline, but I use mailchimp so they should place all the CSS inline for me. 
When I view the email in chrome (by opening the HTML file with the browser) it works perfectly, everything resizes and all the media queries are followed. When I email it or view it in IE or firefox, however, there is absolutely no change, no matter what the screen size or the email client. I'm stuck and haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the link to the HTML file, thanks in advance!

http://www.dealermarketing.com/test/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your sample email.  You have a max-width of 100% set globally on images in your css, but you need to set the actual width of the image to 100%, so that the image will scale.

Here's how you would implement it on your header image:

```
<img mc:edit="header_image" mc:label="header_image" src="http://www.dealermarketing.com/newsletter/dmmtips/DMM-Tips-Header-4.jpg" style="width:100%;" width="100%">
```

You will have to add style="width:100%;" width="100%" to all the images you want to be flexible in the responsive template.

Comment: Thanks mgarabed! I made the actual width of the images 100% and it works now. You can see my new code here: [link](http://www.dealermarketing.com/test/index.html) Now I just need to make it work in outlook!